# No route matches [GET] error in custom put action even though I already specified method: put?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a new action in my post controller called `move_up` which changes the `position` attribute of a post. I got all set up:

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :posts do
    member do
      put :move_up
    end
  end
```

**posts_controller.rb:**
      before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :move_post_up]

```
  def move_up
    @post.update(position: 0)
  end
```

**index.html.erb:**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.content %></td>
    <td><%= post.position %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Move up', move_up_post_path(post) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

But when I click the link I get this error:

```
Started GET "/posts/1/move_up?method=put" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-23 12:09:00 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/posts/1/move_up"):
```

How to fix this?

Comment: hmm, look like the question is still open. just curious, does my code worked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending a `GET` request to an action that only has a `PUT` route defined for it. In this case you would want to specify the put method in your `link_to`, like so:

```
 <td><%= link_to 'Move up', move_up_post_path(post) , method: :put  %></td>
```